# Geometrical Applications of Comple Numbers, roots of Unity

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, geometry, complex-numbers

> If $\omega$ is a non-real cube root of unity, prove that $$\left|\dfrac{x+y\omega+z\omega^2}{x\omega+z+y\omega^2}\right|=1$$

$$$$ Despite trying for a long time, I haven't been able to come up with anything at all. I would greatly appreciate help with this problem. Many thanks!

PS. This question is part of a series on the Rotation Theorem, so presumably the solution will involve that.

Comment: What is $|\omega|?$ Given some $t$ for which you know $|t|,$ what is $|t \omega|?$

Answer (score 3):

so cute.  $|\omega| = 1$ so

$\left|\dfrac{x+y\omega+z\omega^2}{x\omega+z+y\omega^2}\right|=\left|\omega*\dfrac{x+y\omega+z\omega^2}{x\omega+z+y\omega^2}\right|= \left|\dfrac{x\omega+y\omega^2+z}{x\omega+z+y\omega^2}\right|=1$

Answer (score 2):

Note that, for $\omega^3=1$, $\omega^{-1}=\omega^2$, $\omega^{-2}=\omega$, and $|\omega|=1$.  Thus, factor an $\omega$ from the denominator and you are done.